# Changing the content of view dynamically in android

Tags: android, android-view

i am new in android and i got some question about the project that i am doing right now.
i am developing an apps that display a total of 9 images in 3x3 like the picture below.
[image: pict1]

when i press the next button, the images changed to another 9 images. if the remaining images is not 9, then the images will showing according the number of remaining like the picture below. (example the remaining is 6 images)

[image: pict2]

and the questions is:

1. what is the best method to display the images? my idea is create a view that contains 9 ImageViews
2. If i have 2 xml layout, first is the main layout and the second is layout contains the ImageViews, how to insert the second one to first one?
3. and how to insert the images dynamically according to the explanation above?
   [image: question3]

please help me with some code. i very appreciate any help. sorry if my english is not so good.

Thank you in advance.

---

**UPDATE**

i have tried using GridView for this case, this is the first time i using `GridView`, so i using the example from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/) and implement it to mine (i have tried the example that contained there, and it's works).

But, i have checked it many time, there's no error comes from LogCat, no Force Closed, the image didn't show. i have no idea where's the wrong part.

Here's my code:

choosepic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/bg_inner">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/book_inner"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/homeBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/home_btn"
            android:background="@null"
        />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_arrow_btn"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"    
        />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/nextBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/right_arrow"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/prevBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/left_arrow"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/nextBtn"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView1"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:columnWidth="30dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        >

        </GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

animalbutton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
    private final String[] animalValues;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, String[] animalValues) {
        this.context = context;
        this.animalValues = animalValues;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(context);

            // get layout from mobile.xml
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.animalbutton, null);

            // set image based on selected text
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

            String animal = animalValues[position];

            if (animal.equals("Cat")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.anim_cat);
            } else if (animal.equals("Cow")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.anim_cow);
            } else if (animal.equals("Croc")) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.anim_croc);
            } else if(animal.equals("Duck")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.anim_duck);
            } else if(animal.equals("Elephant")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.anim_elephant);
            } else if(animal.equals("Giraffe")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.anim_giraffe);
            } else if(animal.equals("Lion")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.anim_lion);
            } else if(animal.equals("Moose")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.anim_moose);
            } else if(animal.equals("Mouse")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.anim_mouse);
            }else {imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);}


        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return animalValues[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }
}
```

choosepic.java

```
    public class choosepic extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    ImageAdapter mAdapter;
    GridView gridView;
    static final String[] animal = new String[] { 
        "Cat", "Cow","Croc", "Duck", "Elephant", "Giraffe", "Lion", "Moose", "Mouse"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.choosepic);

        mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, animal);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mAdapter.getItem(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

i need some help. thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a look at `GridView` - this is what you're after.  On button clicks for "prev" and "next" you would simply tell the GridView to reload the data - with you already knowing the offset.

Comment: i have tried using `GridView`, i using it as child view and it's showing nothing. no error in LogCat, no Forced Close. lemme post some update about my code

Comment: Have you provided the adapter for your GridView?  It won't display anything on its own - you need the adapter to provide the data and "subviews" to be displayed.

Comment: i have provide my adapter, ImageAdapter it is.

Comment: But ImageAdapter expects images - yet you're passing strings instead.

Comment: please take a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337540/gridview-doesnt-display-content-in-android/11338054#11338054) i have posted the same question about the GridView problem. i changed ImageAdapter and choosepic.java

Answer (score 1):

i've figured out the answer.

1. i am using GridView to display the images. just changes the adapter to change the content
2. this question doesn't have to be answered.
3. same as answer no. 1. the code is like choosepic.xml that i post before.

and the problem why my `` `GridView `` is not displayed images, coz `getCount()` in ImageAdapter is return 0, so no images is displayed in GridView.
i changed `return 0;` with `return animalValues.size()`